# Docosaurus: How can you hide Copy button next to the code example?

Tags: markdown, block, docusaurus

I want to do the opposite from https://gist.github.com/yangshun/55db997ed0f8f4e6527571fc3bee4675.

Can I somehow hide the Copy button from individual Code block (https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/code-blocks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer that I've found on the [Docosaurus support site](https://docusaurus.io/feature-requests/p/hide-the-copy-button-from-individual-code-block).

You can use CSS to hide the button. You just need to assign "your language" to the block where you want to hide the block button.

````
```buttonless
````

You also need to add the following CSS code:

```
.buttonless button {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: The CSS should use class `.language-buttonless` instead and can be added in the `custom.css` file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make individual `code block` not show the copy button… Maybe to following helps you to create a way.

---

**HOW TO DISABLE THE COPY BUTTON FOR ALL CODE BLOCKS**

You will need to `swizzle` it.

**1)** Run:

```
npm run swizzle @docusaurus/theme-classic CodeBlock -- --danger
```

This will create a copy of the code-generator of `code block` inside of the directory `./src/theme/CodeBlock`.

**2)** Navigate to the directory and open `index.js`.

**3)** Inside the file, **find and remove** the following — here was at the ending of the file:

```
[…]
<button
  ref={button}
  type="button"
  aria-label={translate({
    id: 'theme.CodeBlock.copyButtonAriaLabel',
    message: 'Copy code to clipboard',
    description: 'The ARIA label for copy code blocks button',
  })}
  className={clsx(styles.copyButton)}
  onClick={handleCopyCode}>
  {showCopied ? (
    <Translate
      id="theme.CodeBlock.copied"
      description="The copied button label on code blocks">
      Copied
    </Translate>
  ) : (
    <Translate
      id="theme.CodeBlock.copy"
      description="The copy button label on code blocks">
      Copy
    </Translate>
  )}
</button>
[…]
```

**4)** Stop (if running) and start the docusaurus service.

Now you won't see the copy button anymore!

Comment: Thank you! I guess that it isn't possible for individual blocks. I'll create a feature request on Docosaurus site.